# もしただいま大恋愛の最中だったら、本など読むことを勧めしない。特に恋愛小説など。間違っても読んじゃいけない。あなたが現に夢中で打ち込んでいる恋愛の生ましい体験に比べたら、色あせてしまうにちがいないからだ。

Tags: meaning

> 1 - もしただいま大恋愛の最中だったら、本など読むことを勧めしない。特に恋愛小説など。間違っても読んじゃいけない。
>
> 2 - あなたが現に夢中で打ち込んでいる恋愛の生ましい体験に比べたら、色あせてしまうにちがいないからだ。

##### Sentence 1:

Can someone explain in the first sentence what does the 間違っても actually mean or contribute to the sentence?

My interpretation: "IF you are in in the middle of being madly in love with someone, it is recommended not to read romance novels. Even if you make a mistake reading is forbidden."

How can you make a mistake and read a novel? Unless someone holds a gun to your head, why would you make a mistake and read it, what is the mistake?

##### Sentence 2:

I do not understand what this 生ましい体験 means.

My interpretation: If you are actually devoting yourself to being madly in love which is a test, the colours will fade away.

What colours are they talking about?  Is this a metaphor or something? 比喩？

Comment: For 間違っても: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13200/5010 For 生ましい, isn't it a typo for 生々しい? And 体験 is not "test".

Comment: @naruto  Yes I believe you are correct, it is not a type, the book has it written as is.
色あせて-> does this mean the current relationship will lose its colour, or does it mean the romance book contents are losing colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

間違っても is an idiom used to prohibit something strongly. See [this entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82). Since this is an idiom, you can translate it simply as "no matter what" or "never, ever". It literally means "(Don't do it) even by mistake". See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13200/5010), too.

[生々しい](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%94%9F%E3%80%85%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)体験 (生しい is a typo) is "vivid experience". Perhaps you mixed up 体験 (experience) and 試験 (examination/test)? [色あせる](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%89%B2%E8%A4%AA%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B) is just "to pale" or "to lose vividness", and it refers to no particular visible color here. This usage is so common that I don't call it a 比喩. Finally, don't ignore the ～に比べたら pattern ("if/when compared with ～").

> あなたが現に夢中で打ち込んでいる恋愛の生々しい体験に比べたら、[本による体験は]色あせてしまうにちがいないからだ。 (typo fixed)
>
> It's because [the experience of reading] must pale in comparison to the vivid experience of romance you're currently engrossed in.